# Password after MySQL Community Server install from zip

Tags: mysql, windows, passwords, installation, inno-setup

I have been installing the MySQL Community Server from ZIP Archive with the Inno Setup. I have used this install script (little modified) http://dark-it.blogspot.sk/2009/07/inno-setup-mysql-full-script.html, because I need one-click installation for my very simple application, which works with the MySQL database.  My Installation to the Windows XP Professional was successful. Now the MySQL service is running correctly. But my problem is that I don´t know the username and the password for connect to this MySQL server. I have tried changed the username and the password in my.ini file but it wasn´t correct. And I tied blank password too. Can I somehow change the username and the password in this file? Or what is the default password after install? I need import my prepared database to one-click install too. I have located this database to /MyApplication/Data/Database_folder. In this directory are folders as test and performance_schema too. It is correct location?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the MySQL developer pages [how to reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

1. Log on to your system as Administrator.
2. Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it.

   If your server is not running as a service, you may need to use the Task Manager to force it to stop.
3. Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
   ```
4. Save the file. This example assumes that you name the file `C:\mysql-init.txt`.
5. Open a console window to get to the command prompt: From the Start menu, select Run, then enter cmd as the command to be run.
6. Start the MySQL server with the init_file system variable set to name the file (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled):

   ```bash
   C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
   C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
   ```

   If you installed MySQL to a different location, adjust the cd command accordingly.

   The server executes the contents of the file named by the init_file system variable at startup, changing the `'root'@'localhost'` account password.

   To have server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file, add the `--console` option to the mysqld command.

   If you installed MySQL using the MySQL Installation Wizard, you may need to specify a `--defaults-file` option. For example:

   ```bash
   C:\> mysqld
            --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini"
            --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
   ```

   The appropriate `--defaults-file` setting can be found using the Services Manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list, right-click it, and choose the Properties option. The Path to executable field contains the `--defaults-file` setting.
7. After the server has started successfully, delete `C:\mysql-init.txt`.

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the MySQL server and restart it normally. If you run the server as a service, start it from the Windows Services window. If you start the server manually, use whatever command you normally use.

---

About importing you database I would prefer to use a SQL dump they are usually smaller and simple to install with something like this:

```bash
mysql -uroot -prootpwd dbname < dump.sql
```

Comment: You need to [`set the password first`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html), don't you ?

Comment: @TLama however Mato said that he tried an empty password, but your link says "The initial root account passwords are empty".

Comment: I am sorry, but now I am continuing with testing and the problem is that before authentication process my application returns this error: “MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.” So the problem is probably in installation the MySql with Inno setup and it is not the problem with the password. Do you know what is the potentially cause of this problem, please?

Comment: Did you make sure that the service is running?

Comment: Yes, the service running correctly.

Comment: Can you connect to the server in cmd?

Comment: When I enter: 

...\bin>mysql
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

...\bin>mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

So the connection in cmd doesn´t work :-(

Comment: So I have resolved the problem with the connection. I have added to my.ini file line - bind-address="127.0.0.1". But now I am not connect with my database, which I add to Data directory. On my computer I have set MySQL password "toor". When I used this password on the test computer, my application returns error "nameofdatabase.table does not exist". When I used the blank password and connect to databse (that is imported), my application returns error "authentication for this password failed..."

Comment: But when I used databse test (it is default example database) with blank password the connection is correct. So password is associated with databse? Can you help me please with the correct connect to the my database?

Comment: Now it seems to be a permission problem. Did you grand the permissions? How did you exactly import your database. Which [storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html) do you use MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I only copied the folder with my database from my computer to the test computer (to MySQL location /direction/). It will be possible problem. But I don´t know how to copy my database with Inno Setup other way... Because the complete installation process on the test computer has to be one-click for the end user.

Comment: The storrage engine is very important for recovering a database. Try to use mysqldump that is more portable.

Comment: @rekire Thak you for help.

Comment: Actually, after all those years, with 8.0.33, this is what you would type into your init file:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';

Comment: I updated my big quote